# How kill background child processes on bash script exit when child processes repeatedly spawned and kill -9

Tags: bash

My bash script is indended to repeatedly start a program and shut it down after it executes for about KILL_EVERY seconds. The problem is that I stop the script with CTRL+C and it leaves behind the last process it instantiated.

I tried setting up a trap for SIGINT and killing process $ID but what happens is that the loop breaks. I suspect this is because somehow the trap activates after $PROGRAM is first killed and kills the next instance if it exists.

How do I fix it such that the script repeatedly starts, awaits KILL_EVERY seconds, then kills $PROGRAM but on CTRL+C does not leave the $PROGRAM instance running in the background?

```
KILL_EVERY=${1:-0}
PROGRAM=path/to/program
if [ $KILL_EVERY -gt 0]; then
    while true ; do
        ID=exec $PROGRAM &
        sleep $KILL_EVERY
        kill -9 $ID
    done
else
    exec $PROGRAM
fi
```

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and operating-system-provided tools; better form is to use lowercase names for your own variables. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: (I'm also not clear what you mean to accomplish by exporting an environment named `ID` with the value `exec` into the execution environment in which `$PROGRAM` is run; you **are not** assigning the PID of your program to `ID`).

Comment: ...what you meant is presumably something like `foo & foo_pid=$!`

Comment: Yes, I ended up using $!. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
trap 'kill -HUP -$$; exit' SIGINT
KILL_EVERY=${1:-0}
PROGRAM=path/to/program
if [ $KILL_EVERY -gt 0 ]; then
    while true ; do
        $PROGRAM & ID=$!
        sleep $KILL_EVERY
        kill -9 $ID
    done
else
    exec $PROGRAM
fi
```

This will kill everything in the process group when you do `ctrl+c`.

Comment: This is most certainly buggy. Without evaluating any other aspect of it for correctness, `ID=exec $PROGRAM &` does not assign a value `kill` can use to the variable named `ID`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're correct. I simply gave a method to remove all background processes started by the script, but the code snippet in the answer is definitely buggy. Thanks for bringing attention to this :)